# How to find out is a program run with nohup or not?

Tags: linux, shell, process, nohup

There is no difference in `ps -ef | grep sleep` output to commands:

`nohup sleep 60 &`

`sleep 60 &`

In which way can I discover that program is run with `nohup`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You need to know pid of process you want to look at. You can use `pgrep` or `jobs -l`:

  ```
  jobs -l
  [1]-  3730 Running    sleep 1000 &
  [2]+  3734 Running    nohup sleep 1000 &
  ```

  Actually, this might already tell you the answer, unless you logged off and logged in again (then `jobs -l` will not show anything).
- Take a look at `/proc/<pid>/fd`. Processes started with `nohup` will list `nohup.out` files:

  ```
  mvp@linux:~$ ls -l /proc/3734/fd
  total 0
  l-wx------ 1 mvp mvp 64 Oct 29 02:32 0 -> /dev/null
  l-wx------ 1 mvp mvp 64 Oct 29 02:32 1 -> /home/mvp/nohup.out
  l-wx------ 1 mvp mvp 64 Oct 29 02:32 2 -> /home/mvp/nohup.out
  ```

  and started without `nohup` will not:

  ```
  mvp@linux:~$ ls -l /proc/3730/fd
  total 0
  lrwx------ 1 mvp mvp 64 Oct 29 02:28 0 -> /dev/pts/1
  lrwx------ 1 mvp mvp 64 Oct 29 02:28 1 -> /dev/pts/1
  lrwx------ 1 mvp mvp 64 Oct 29 02:28 2 -> /dev/pts/1
  ```